# Not able to loging into moody's website programatically

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am trying to download some articles from the some websites for trend analysis. While I can use the url of some of the websites to get the html content as a response , I am not able to do so with the moody's website . The website requires me to login to do any sort of download. URL of the moody's website is - 
https://www.moodys.com/Login.aspx

I am using C# . Any help to log in programmatically is appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately your question isn't for this venue - you should ask Moody's if they offer an API or service to obtain information in such a way. They obviously treat their content as _proprietary_ hence the login.

Comment: Reminds me of that question where OP asked how to automatically pass Captcha tests ...